# there is no chage to the dataset even after random affine (pytorch)

Tags: pytorch, transform, mnist

I downloaded two version of mnist dataset: one without any transformation, one with random affinement and normalization.

w/o transformation code:

```
mnist_train = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root='MNIST_data/', 
                          train=True, 
                          transform=transforms.ToTensor(), 
                          download=True)
```

with transformation code:

```
train_transforms = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.RandomAffine(degrees=30),
     transforms.ToTensor(),
     transforms.Normalize(mean=(0.5,), std=(0.5,))])

augmented_data = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root='aug_data/',
                                        train=True,
                                        transform=train_transforms,
                                        download=True)
```

I printed several samples from those two, but the results were all identical.
can anybody figure out the cause??

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no augmented MNIST dataset and `download=True` just downloads the same plain MNIST dataset in the `root`s you have specified.

The transform is applied online when you access an element of the dataset, e.g. `augmented_data[0]`. In this way, the transformation you have specified is applied to the first image of MNIST.

If you want to check the difference you, therefore, have to display the images accessed in this way with some visualization tool, e.g. by using `matplotlib.imshow`:

### Code

```py
import torch
import torchvision
from torchvision import transforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mnist_train = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root='MNIST_data/', 
                          train=True, 
                          transform=transforms.ToTensor(), 
                          download=True)

train_transforms = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.RandomAffine(degrees=30),
     transforms.ToTensor(),
     transforms.Normalize(mean=(0.5,), std=(0.5,))])

# you can use the same root, since the data is the same
augmented_data = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root='MNIST_data/',  
                                        train=True,
                                        transform=train_transforms,
                                        download=True)

im = mnist_train[0][0][0]
aug_im = augmented_data[0][0][0]

# Normal image
plt.imshow(im, cmap="gray")
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()

# Agumented image
plt.imshow(aug_im, cmap="gray")
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

### Result

##### Normal Image

[image: normal image]

##### Augmented Image

[image: augmented image]

Note the difference of value ranges in the right-sided color bar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Setting download=False raises an error "Dataset not found. You can download=True to download it". did i get your msg correctly?? did you mean to get augmented data i needed to set download=True???

Comment: Moreover, code "plt.imshow(augmented_data.data[0], cmap='gray_r')" still returns an unchagned image.

Comment: `download=False` will raise an error when changing the folder, since PyTorch assumes the dataset has been already downloaded and located in the folder specified.

For your purposes, you can just set the same folder for both the normal and augmented version. The transformation will be applied at runtime after you access the data. 

I have added a code example to be more clear.

Comment: thank you so much for your help!